# If $E$ is measurable and $0<m(E)<\infty$, then for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ there is an open interval I s.t $m(E \cap I)>(1-\epsilon)m(I)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that is $E$ is measurable and $0<m(E)<\infty$, then for any $0<\epsilon<1$ there is an open interval $I$ such that $m(E \cap I)>(1-\epsilon)m(I)$

How would I solve this without using The Lebesgue density theorem

Comment: I don't think the answer to that question is an answer to this one.  @LevBan

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  The questioner of the question made typo in title.The answer is explaining two different inequalities :)